# Chrome or FF as IE-component replacement?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, integration

I'm currently launching IE w/o toolbars/url from NAV to get a more clean experience.

IE has rendering problems, (related to opacity etc) so:

Can I start FF or chrome w/o toolbars and set width/height. I'm browsing through the command switches, cannot find a way to turn off tabs etc though.

Thankful for any advices. IE, as always, drives me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all projects on FF seems dead currently,

Chrome has the feature natively,
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710

Over and out.